# Show Img thumbnail when hovering a hyperlink (JQuery, CSS?)

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table with football players, all of the players names are hyperlinks. When the user clicks on a link a lightbox event starts and shows a picture of the chosen player. So what I want to happen, is that when the user hovers over the link, a thumbnail of that actual players picture shows.

Comment: You can use 
<a>Link
<div><img src="/image" /></div>
</a>
in css: 
a>div { display: none; }
a:hover>div { display: block; }

Answer (score 3):

Simply st. like this:

```
<a href="">
    Player name
    <img src="thumb.jpg">
</a>

<style>
a {position: relative;}
img {display: none; width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red; position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 0;}
a:hover img {display: block;}
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zrcgfmh7/

Image has `position: absolute;` to avoid move other elements in the rest of document.